# put Action Bar Sherlock On in bottom by code

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

i need to put Sherlock  Action Bar On in bottom

my code

```
    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
            .parseColor("#383a6d")));
    mActionBar.setSplitBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
            .parseColor("#1c1ab6")));
    mActionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
            .parseColor("#1d1d5a")));
tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Discover").setIcon(discoverIco)
            .setTabListener(tabListener);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

    // Create second Tab
    tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Join").setIcon(joinIco)
            .setTabListener(tabListener);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);
```

my app show like this image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i143U.jpg]

how can put the tabs or action bar in bottom instead in the top

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest add this code `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"`
For Example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:versionCode="431"
          android:versionName="4.3.1"
          package="com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos">
```

and in your activity add this code again:

```
<activity android:label="@string/activity_name" 
          android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
          android:name=".SampleList" android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
```

Comment: android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" can not under <manifest tag .